# Check & Change License - PyCharm IDE

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide

### Description of the problem

I want to check which edition of PyCharm I use.
I mean, if the *PyCharm* edition is *Community* or *Professional*. If it turns out that I use a *Community Edition* I would like to change it to *Professional* as I can do due to the fact that I am student.

### What have I done in order to do this?

I found on the [JetBrain's site](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/register.html) how to do it but in *Configure Tab* on *Welcome Screen* I don't have anything like *Manage License*.

[image: My Welcome Screen on localhost]

### Question

Can somebody help me and tell me how to check the edition of PyCharm distribution?

Comment: Have you tried `Get Help | About` ??. P.S. The shortcut for `Help | Find Action...` (`Ctrl+Shift+A` on Windows) will work on Welcome screen as well. You can then type `about` and get the same About window.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Solution

The solution to this problem was to install PyCharm Professional Edition.